# How can I retrieve geospatial data from a WMS (web map service) using GoogleMaps in a Flutter Mobile App?

Tags: flutter, openstreetmap, wms, fluttermap

I'm trying to display geospatial data stored in a WMS (Web Mapping Service) into a Flutter App.
I was using the FlutterMap library and it worked but now I need to retrieve FeatureID's of the geospatial data and turns out that FlutterMap can't do that (or that's what I find on the internet and AI chats tell me). So now, I'm trying to do it using GoogleMaps library but I can't find any documentation of how GoogleMaps works fetching tiles from a WMS.
If you know how to make my Flutter App retrieve the geospatial data from a WMS please help me and if you know another way to do this and then retrieve the FeatureID's of the geospatial data I'm also open to new libraries or ways to do it.

This is my code so far using FlutterMap library but I can't go further into retrieving the Feature ID of the tile displaying on the Simulator now. [The blue lines are the data (a Shapefile in this case) that is saved in the WMS.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9pNK.png)